# playframework change heap size

Tags: java, playframework, jvm, sbt

My PlayFramework app always starts with only 256mb ram. Is there a way to increase the default ram?

I start my application with `sbt run`

Thanks in advance

I got this error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit `sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt` and set `-Xmx1024M` for sbt globally.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sovled:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djline.terminal=none -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dsbt.global.base=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt-global-pluginstub -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -classpath C:\Users\User\.IntelliJIdea2018.3\config\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar xsbt.boot.Boot "project ji_approvalmachine_processes" run
```

Its not generic solution. But you can use relative paths or enviroment variables instead of the absolute path.